# WCF: Configuring maxbuffersize on IDE-created service

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2012

In the past, the experience I made with WCF always based on Castle Windsor and its WCF facility where it was pretty easy to configure binding parameters.

At this project, I need to work with those auto-generated WCF code-behind approach using Visual Studio (Project -> Add new item -> WCF service). 
Now I need to adjust the maxbuffersize parameter of my binding at server-side, but the only configuration Visual Studio generated for me is the following (Web.config):

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

I wonder that Visual Studio does not generate any binding or endpoint configuration. What is the best approach to attach a specific binding through Web.config?

If it's possible I would favor XML-based configuration over adjusting binding parameters programmatically.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just create a binding and endpoint with default settings for your service and alter only the maxBufferSize setting. That is the preferred approach (over configuring it in code).

Answer (score 2):

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="*********" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
    <basicHttpBinding>
<bindings>
```

maybe this can help.

Comment: Yeah I already got this far, thank you. I just wonder how the endpoint gets aware of the binding. I guess it should refer the name of the binding somehow?

Comment: @mbue see this: <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="this is your binding name" contract="" />